# Linux - download torrent file via two network interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, bittorrent

I have 2 different network connections, so I want to speed up torrents loading by using these networks simultaneously. I assume that each network has different torrents peers and one torrent part can be loaded faster through one of connections than through the other, and vice versa.

Does anybody know how can I do that?

Comment: I have never tried it myself, but **1.** This guy, https://kakku.wordpress.com/2007/11/03/combine-two-connections-for-a-single-torrent-download-routing-through-multiple-uplinks/ claims he has two ways to do it, and **2.**, Azureus can deal with multiple interfaces (again a claim on the same Web page). I am skeptical, but maybe I am wrong.

Comment: @g4s8 isn t multipath tcp what you want?